# Aggregate failure notifications into a single email for a DAG in Airflow

Tags: airflow

So I have a DAG with lots of tasks, while some of them do fail during the day. I'm wondering if there is a way to aggregate all the failure notifications into a single email for a DAG in Airflow

Answer (score 0):

Two main ways to go about this:

1. Having a task at the end of your DAG that uses a callback which will retrieve all failed tasks in that DAG and send an email with the info:

```py
from airflow.utils.email import send_email

def custom_callback(context):
    dag_run = context.get("dag_run")
    task_instances = dag_run.get_task_instances(state="failed")

    msg = f"These ti failed: {task_instances}"
    subject = f"Failed tasks for DAG {dag_run}"
    send_email(to=<your email>, subject=subject, html_content=msg)
```

(adapted from [source](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/error-notifications-in-airflow#custom-notifications))

2. Using a call to the [Airflow API listing tasks](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#operation/get_task_instances) with a state failed for a specifc dag or dag_run.